# How to set a fixed position to the x-axis in core-plot

Tags: ios, core-plot

In my application I have a core-plot graph. The labels of the x-axis display in the graph area. This is a capture:

[image]

I don't know what is wrong. I'm using expandRangeByFactor for yRange with this code

```
[yRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(2.1f)];
```

But the problem is that when the data changes, the x-axis labels move up or down. I don't understand this behavior.

Is possible to fix the x-axis labels to one position, always at the bottom of graph.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell what's wrong without seeing your code, but you could try setting an axis constraint on the x axis:

```
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
axisSet.xAxis.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
```

Comment: Thank you Jeff for responding. I know is very hard to know what is wrong. I appreciate you if you can check the code in this zip file http://1drv.ms/P0otnQ . In this code I include the constraint like you  answer me, but I don't see any change in x axis. I guess that I use another property that makes the constraint doesn't any action.

Comment: Jeff, I found the solution with axis constraint, with this code that you responding me I have solve this issue. I had inserted the constraint in bad place in my code, when I place the constraint after define the x Axis  the labels of x axis are correctly display. I have -18.0 as value of constraint in my case, I guess I have another issue in my code because with 0.0 as value, the labels would must display correctly.